# Install ns-3 on Mac problems

Tags: python, installation, ns-3

Just download ns-3 and I guess the software packet is fine. I am really new for ns-3.

Actually there are 2 questions:

1. `# Skip NSC (platform not supported)` so does that mean the Mac cannot support NSC and so what ?
2. `In file included from ./ns3/trace-source-accessor.h:24:
   ./ns3/callback.h:469:54: error: expression with side effects will be evaluated despite
     being used as an operand to 'typeid' [-Werror,-Wpotentially-evaluated-expression]
                       "got=" << Demangle ( typeid (*other).name () ) << std::endl <<`
   I cannot find anything about this on google. Can anyone help to see what happened here ?

Answer (score 0):

What way of installing did you use? I install NS3 all the time on my Mac using the manual installation: download latest version and run ./build.py install.

I haven't encountered the NSC error before. NSC is the Network Simulator Cradle and you don't need it for normal operations. You might have enabled it with "`./waf configure --enable-nsc`".

Since I develop code for an embedded platform, I want to use GCC instead of the default CLANG compiler. I noticed different compiler behaviour between them. CLANG looked a bit more strict. You might have the same problem. If you have GCC you could switch to GCC by using: (my own config setup)

```
CXX=g++-7 CC=gcc-7 CFLAGS="-g" ./waf configure  --enable-tests --enable-examples --disable-python
```

EDIT:
I just run a test and "./waf configure --enable-nsc" is not recognized 
https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.2/manual/manual_45.html